# How can I copy data from 1 existing database to another existing database on two remote servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, copy, sql-server-2012, remote-server

I have **Server_A** with **DB_A** and **Server_B** with **DB_B**, both of these are remote servers that I have no root access to.

**Server_A** is SQL 2012 and **DB_A** is set in Compatibility level 2008

**Server_B** is SQL 2008 and **DB_B** is set in Compatibility level 2008, of course.

I need to copy the data, including relationships and keys from **DB_A** to **DB_B**. How can this be done?

Using the import or export wizard I've only been able to move the data and all the relationships are list. Please give a guy a hand and teach him something!

Comment: Have you tried backing up the database and restoring it within the other management studio ?

Comment: I only backs up the database on the server its hosted on, I cannot remotely backup as far as I know.

Comment: To recreate each table's structure (including the keys), you can right click and **Script Table As->Create To->File**.  Then run that script on the remote servers to create an exact duplicate of each tables structure.  Then use the import/export wizard to transfer the data over.  But @PhaDaPhunk's suggestion is probably a more comprehensive option.

Comment: @PowerUser, can I do that to an existing database? I'm limited on my commands due to my access. I cannot use a script to create a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to right-click on the source database in SSMS and select Tasks > Generate Scripts. This will show a wizard which when completed will produce a text file with all the SQL statements needed to replicate the database on a new system.

The neat thing about the wizard is that it gives you a set options so that you can decide what is in the final output. So you get to 
pick if you just want the data or the table structures or both.

The final result might not be a good option for large databases but it is very portable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can back up to a `.bak` file. 
Where you want to restore it is totally up to you.

If it doesn't work for some reason (it should work fine) you can always try to copy your database [like so](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx).

These two steps will copy the database intierly. **Including the relationships and keys**.

This is the only alternative I've found for your problem [since you don't have sysadmin rights](http://www.markus-schneider.net/2009/08/how-to-copy-ms-sql-database-from-one.html).

Comment: "You must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role on both the source and destination servers." Sadly, I am not. This is going from 1 Plesk MS SQL DB to another Plesk MS SQL DB. I have no admin level access.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the without sysadmin part. I will update my answer